# Jasmine toMatch url + uuid

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

After sending a click that causes the creation of a new resource, I'm using this to wait for the browser to get redirected to the newly created resource:

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return url == 'https://dev.mysite.com/resource/'+/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/
        });
    });
```

The problem is that I can't get the url==/myUrl to resolve to true

Here's a sample url I'm trying to return true on, the portion after the resource/ changes with each test:

```
https://dev.mysite.com/resource/54d4ee554bf01d2a7e4e8058
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        var re = /resource\/[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/;
        return url.match(re);
    });
});
```

Note that slash inside the url has to be escaped with a backslash.